# Troubleshooting Scala Spark Configurations/Environments

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, apache-spark

Running windows 8.1, Java 1.8, Scala 2.10.5, Spark 1.4.1, Scala IDE (Eclipse 4.4), Ipython 3.0.0 and [Jupyter Scala](https://github.com/alexarchambault/jupyter-scala).

I'm relatively new to Scala and Spark and I'm seeing an issue where certain RDD commands like collect and first return the "Task not serializable" error. What's unusual to me is I see that error in Ipython notebooks with the Scala kernel or the Scala IDE. However when I run the code directly in the spark-shell I do not receive this error.

I would like to setup these two environments for more advanced code evaluation beyond the shell. I have little expertise in troubleshooting this type of issue and determining what to look for; if you can provide guidance on how to get started with resolving this kind of issue that would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
val logFile = "s3n://[key:[key secret]@mortar-example-data/airline-data"
val sample = sc.parallelize(sc.textFile(logFile).take(100).map(line => line.replace("'","").replace("\"","")).map(line => line.substring(0,line.length()-1)))
val header = sample.first
val data = sample.filter(_!= header)
data.take(1)
data.count
data.collect
```

Stack Trace

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:315)
    org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:305)
    org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:132)
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1893)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:311)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:310)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:310)
    cmd49$$user$$anonfun$4.apply(Main.scala:188)
    cmd49$$user$$anonfun$4.apply(Main.scala:187)
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkConf, value: org.apache.spark.SparkConf@5976e363)
    - field (class: cmd12$$user, name: conf, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkConf)
    - object (class cmd12$$user, cmd12$$user@39a7edac)
    - field (class: cmd49, name: $ref$cmd12, type: class cmd12$$user)
    - object (class cmd49, cmd49@3c2a0c4f)
    - field (class: cmd49$$user, name: $outer, type: class cmd49)
    - object (class cmd49$$user, cmd49$$user@774ea026)
    - field (class: cmd49$$user$$anonfun$4, name: $outer, type: class cmd49$$user)
    - object (class cmd49$$user$$anonfun$4, <function0>)
    - field (class: cmd49$$user$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$3, name: $outer, type: class cmd49$$user$$anonfun$4)
    - object (class cmd49$$user$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$3, <function1>)
    org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:81)
    org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:312)
    org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:305)
    org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:132)
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1893)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:311)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:310)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:310)
    cmd49$$user$$anonfun$4.apply(Main.scala:188)
    cmd49$$user$$anonfun$4.apply(Main.scala:187)
```

Comment: Why are you using sc.textFile inside of sc.parallelize?!?

Answer (score 1):

@Ashalynd was right about the fact that sc.textFile already creates and RDD. You don't need sc.parallelize in that case. [documentation here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext)

So considering your example, this is what you'll need to do :

```
// Read your data from S3
val logFile = "s3n://[key:[key secret]@mortar-example-data/airline-data"
val rawRDD = sc.textFile(logFile)

// Fetch the header
val header =  rawRDD.first

// Filter on the header than map to clean the line
val sample = rawRDD.filter(!_.contains(header)).map { 
 line => line.replaceAll("['\"]","").substring(0,line.length()-1)
}.takeSample(false,100,12L) // takeSample returns a fixed-size sampled subset of this RDD in an array
```

It's better to use the `takeSample` function :

> def *takeSample*(withReplacement: Boolean, num: Int, seed: Long = Utils.random.nextLong): Array[T]
>
> **withReplacement** : whether sampling is done with replacement
>
> **num** : size of the returned sample
>
> **seed** : seed for the random number generator

**Note 1 :** the sample is an Array[String], so if you wish to transform it to an RDD, you can use the `parallelize` function as followed :

```
val sampleRDD = sc.parallelize(sample.toSeq)
```

**Note 2 :** If you wish to take a sample RDD directly from your `rawRDD.filter(...).map(...)` , you can use the `sample` function that returns an RDD[T]. Nevertheless, you'll need to specify an fraction of the data you need instead of a specific number.

Comment: `val header = sample.first` won't work though, because `sample` doesn't exist at that point yet?

Comment: My bad. That should be rawRDD.first

Comment: but your header is then different than the header made from sample. Sample clears data, reduces the length of every data element by 1, then extracts the header and filters data against that header. Taking the raw data which are not equal to the unprocessed first element is probably not going to yield the same set.

Comment: A header must be unique for all data, wether it's sampled of full. It usually defines the parameter's name. So I don't agree on that point!

Answer (score 0):

sc.textFile already creates distributed dataset (check the documentation ). You don't need sc.parallelize in that case, but - as eliasah properly noted - you need to turn the result into an RDD again, if you want to have an RDD.

```
val selection = sc.textFile(logFile). // RDD
take(100). // collection
map(_.replaceAll("['\"]",""). // use regex to match both chars
map(_.init) // a method that returns all elements except the last
// turn the resulting collection into RDD again
val sample = sc.parallelize(selection)
```

Comment: sample is not an RDD thought here!

Comment: why? textFile is supposed to create an RDD isn't it?

Comment: Yes, then take(100) returns a Array[String] which you are mapping on. So, you'll just have an Array of Strings on which you have applied the replaceAll and init function.